# Find an approximate probability that more than $5$ cars in the shipment have defective mufflers?

Tags: probability

One percent of certain model cars have defective mufflers. Suppose $400$ cars of this certain model are ready to ship.

(a) find an approximate probability that more than $5$ cars in the shipment have defective mufflers?

(b) find an approximate probability that between $3$ and $6$ cars (inclusive) in the shipment have defective mufflers?

Work: 
(a) I know the long way to do this $P(5) + P(6)......P(400)$ but I'm not sure how to approximate it?

(b) Would this just be $P(3) + P(4) + P(5) + P(6)$?

Comment: Think of your case as an assembly line, that puts out one item every second, for 400 seconds, where there's a 1 percent chance the item will be defective.

Instead you can think of an assembly line that outputs items *on average* one per second, but each instant the choice is made.

Comment: By the way, more than $5$ means $6$ or more, so your long sum should have started with $P(6)$. Shorter is $1-[P(0)+P(1)+\cdots +P(5)]$. This can be readily calculated using the binomial distribution, but I suspect you are expected to use the Poisson approximation.

Answer (score 3):

P(n) = $0.01^n$ * $0.99^m$ where m = 400 - n

(a) 1 - (P(0)+ .... + P(5))

(b) P(3)+P(4)+P(5)+P(6)